# Where to get descriptions of (X)HTML tags & CSS properties from? (for parsing application)

Tags: xhtml, tags

I need the definition of XHTML tags with their properties... last time I asked here you told me to use DTD, so I did wrote a small script using XML_DTD (PEAR extension) that parses it for me ... However its not enough. It doesn't contain any tag descriptions (as it is for validators ;) ) ... now I need to have short descriptions of tags, I don't really like the idea of writing them by myself (or copying & pasting from some site) so I'm looking for some document where I can get it from by writing a script (like INI, XML, or any easily-readable format) ...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For XHTML there are XML schema documents available that contains the information about xHTML document structure and they have an inline documentation that you could use. Since XML Schemas are also valid XML documents they should be easy to parse.

Here are the links:

- [xHTML 1.0 Strict](http://www.w3.org/2002/08/xhtml/xhtml1-strict.xsd)
- [xHTML 1.0 Frameset](http://www.w3.org/2002/08/xhtml/xhtml1-frameset.xsd)
- [xHTML 1.0 Transitional](http://www.w3.org/2002/08/xhtml/xhtml1-transitional.xsd)

Comment: the schemas you provided are much more suitable for my needs, however its still not exactly what I'm looking for as it lacks description of parameters ...